# Drupal Privatemsg Pre-Populate Recipients

Tags: drupal-7

I am pre-populating the recipients in the Privatemsg module, but cant figure out where I am going wrong.

I successfully print out the options into a select list in the format...
55 => Chris
(uid => username)

Here is my module code...

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'privatemsg_new') {
        global $user; 
        if (in_array('Venue Manager', $user->roles) || in_array('Couples Page Manager', $user->roles)) {
            $form['recipient']['#title'] = 'Choose which of your Couples you would like to message.';
            $form['recipient']['#type'] = 'select';
            $form['recipient']['#size'] = 1;
            $options = couples_page_messages_recipients();
            $form['recipient']['#options'] = $options;
            array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#validate'], 'couples_page_messages_validate');
        }
        if (in_array('Couples Page Manager', $user->roles)) {
            $form['recipient']['#title'] = 'Send a message to your venue.';
        }
    }   
}

function MYMODULE_recipients() {
    global $user;
    $options = array();
    if (in_array('Manager', $user->roles)) {
        $result = db_query('SELECT `entity_id` FROM `field_data_field_parent_user` WHERE `field_parent_user_target_id` = :uid', array(':uid' => $user->uid));
        if (is_array($result) || is_object($result)) {
            foreach ($result as $record) {
                $child = user_load($record->entity_id);
                $childlist[$child->name] = $child->name;
            }
        }
    }
    if (in_array('Page Manager', $user->roles)) {
        $result = db_query('SELECT `field_parent_user_target_id` FROM `field_data_field_parent_user` WHERE `entity_id` = :uid', array(':uid' => $user->uid));
        if (is_array($result) || is_object($result)) {
            foreach ($result as $record) {
                $child = user_load($record->field_parent_user_target_id);
            $childlist[$child->name] = $child->name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $childlist;
}

function MYMODULE_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $recipients = $form_state['values']['recipient'];
  $usernames = array();
  foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $user = user_load((int) $recipient);
    $usernames[] = $user->name;
  }
  $form_state['values']['recipient'] = implode(', ', $usernames);
}
```

The form loads ok, you select the user from the drop down, fill out the message and click send, and then the following error shows...

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   MYMODULE_validate() (line 60 of
>   /example.com/sites/all/modules/custom/MYMODULE/MYMODULE.module). You
>   must include at least one valid recipient.

Can someone help see whats wrong?

If I add a dsm($form_state) to the validation function, I can see that..

```
$form['values']['recipient'] = me@example.com
```

This means the recipient is being passed through successfully, so im not sure where its getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ditch the extra validation function. Looking at the validate array, sufficient validation was already being performed and didn't need to be overridden.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'privatemsg_new') {
        global $user; 
        if (in_array('Venue Manager', $user->roles) || in_array('Couples Page Manager', $user->roles)) {
            $form['recipient']['#title'] = 'Choose which of your Couples you would like to message.';
            $form['recipient']['#type'] = 'select';
            $form['recipient']['#size'] = 1;
            $options = couples_page_messages_recipients();
            $form['recipient']['#options'] = $options;
        }
        if (in_array('Couples Page Manager', $user->roles)) {
            $form['recipient']['#title'] = 'Send a message to your venue.';
        }
    }   
}

function MYMODULE_recipients() {
    global $user;
    $options = array();
    if (in_array('Manager', $user->roles)) {
        $result = db_query('SELECT `entity_id` FROM `field_data_field_parent_user` WHERE `field_parent_user_target_id` = :uid', array(':uid' => $user->uid));
        if (is_array($result) || is_object($result)) {
            foreach ($result as $record) {
                $child = user_load($record->entity_id);
                $childlist[$child->name] = $child->name;
            }
        }
    }
    if (in_array('Page Manager', $user->roles)) {
        $result = db_query('SELECT `field_parent_user_target_id` FROM `field_data_field_parent_user` WHERE `entity_id` = :uid', array(':uid' => $user->uid));
        if (is_array($result) || is_object($result)) {
            foreach ($result as $record) {
                $child = user_load($record->field_parent_user_target_id);
            $childlist[$child->name] = $child->name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $childlist;
}
```

As soon as it avoided this validation, the form submitted and message sent.